# In checking "Use V8 as JavaScript engine" condition, some macros recorded in the same condition cannot run successfully

Tags: macros, emeditor

I checked the box `Use V8 as JavaScript engine`.

The `demo.txt` could be:

```
"date": "2019-11-22T20:49:21"
"text": ""

"date": "2019-11-22T20:49:24"
"text": ""
```

I record the macros that replace `\n\n` by `\n`, then I save the macros as `Delete redundant newlines.jsee`.

```
document.selection.Replace("\\n\\n","\\n",eeReplaceAll | eeFindReplaceRegExp,0);
```

But, when I run the `.jsee` for the same `demo.txt`, here comes the `V8 nesting issues occured` warning.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEOYS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWJDs.png)

By the way, this problem have not happen in the unchecked case.

What's wrong?

I don't know too much about the `JavaScript`, so I don't know how to upgrade(or fix) the macros recorded in the case of unchecking `Use V8 as JavaScript engine` option.

And another quetion, can I set breakpoints for macros files for which help me optimize the macros?

Comment: This issue is a bug and we will fix it as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you.
I also found aome infomations in [this technical review](https://www.emeditor.com/emeditor-core/emeditor-v22-1-0-released-including-technical-review/).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using EMEDITOR PROFESSIONAL. According to the manufacturer page EMEDITOR FREE V21.4 "Record and Run only, no scriptable macros". [official website](https://www.emeditor.com/text-editor-features/history/emeditor-free/)

Destruction to your second question, I use "alert" to stop the script at a certain position or to display a certain value of a variable at a position. Also the line "Redraw = false;" is commented out (//) for debugging.
e.g.

```
if (....){
    ....
    alert("debug loop true")
}else{
    ...
    alert("debug loop else")
}
```

[image]

To the first question, I think I read (can't find the article right now) that the Macro Recorder records in javascript as before (not V8). As you wrote, unchecking "Use V8 as JavaScript engine".

For a simple test, copy the line "alert(" Hello EmEditor")" to the clipboard and then select "Run Clipboard" from the macro menu. If successful, a small window will be displayed. In my environment it is also necessary that the saved script runs first through the following steps:

- Menu Macro

  - Customize...
- My Macros

  - Add (select Macro file)

This is necessary for security reasons.